# How to swap particular row among list of row based on value scanned in text box in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, html-table

I'm developing a web application in that I'm generating table row dynamically based on value entered in text box. Only one condition, if I enter same value twise (one after another), it should not add row. If I enter 10 different values and at 10th time if I enter the value which I entered previously that row should come to top in the table. (It should not add again).

For example I am entering value like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` and 11th time I am entering value 1 then in that table 1 row should come at top `(1,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2)`.

If I entered 1,1 then it should add row only one time. Please help me to complete this. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var WholeString="";

    /*To Search Shipment id through webservice: Begin */    
    $('#searchkey').change(function(){
        Allboxes=new Array();
        Allboxes[0]=0;

            $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '@routes.Application.searchkey()',
            data : {
                searchkey : $(this).val(),
                orgname: 'FB'
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("success"+data);
                var arr = data.split('&');


                if((arr[0]!="null")&&(arr[1]!="null")&&(!WholeString.contains(arr[0])))
                {
                    WholeString=WholeString+"::"+arr[0];

                    var table='<tr  class="active" style="height:40px;">';
                    table += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="name1" value="1" checked /></td>';
                    table += '<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm dark_button width-150px">'+arr[0]+'</button></td>';
                    table += '<td>'+arr[1]+'</td>';
                    table+='<td><i  style="color:green;font-size:18px" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>';
                    table += '</tr>';

            // append table in box_content
                $("#boxnumberarea").append(table);

            // creates tbody and append to last inserted table
                var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo('#boxnumberarea table:last');
                Allboxes[0]=arr[0];
                }
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("failed");

            }
              });
         $(this).val('');


/*To Search Shipment id through webservice: End */  
    });
    if (!('contains' in String.prototype)) String.prototype.contains = function (str, startIndex) {
        return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
    };
});

  </script>
```

Assume inside tbody that ajax portion is been appending.Now code will not allow duplicate value. Along with that i want above feature as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, while adding rows compare data and if found prepend that row else a new row.

I've setup a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wv5jLmqd/). Check it out.

**Updated** Sample to match your structure : http://jsfiddle.net/wv5jLmqd/1/ .

Code snippet for checking existing similar row :

```
    $("#tab tr td:first-child").each(function (idx) {
        if ($(this).text() === num) {
            foundAt = idx;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Adding rows :

```
    if (foundAt !== -1) {
        $row = $("#tab tr").eq(foundAt);
    } else {
        $row = $("<tr><td>" + num + "</td><td> SAMPLE TEXT</td>");
    }
```

Refer :

1. [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
2. [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)
3. [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: I am trying to apply to my code. In my code value of this line is coming always empty $("#boxnumberarea tr td:nth-child(3)") . Please help me out. Because of this its not working properly. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi its working. I used children in the $(this).children('button').text()

Comment: That's great! @user3609146